# How to Handle Text like W O R K E X P E R I E N C E extracted from document in NLP?

Tags: nlp, data-science

I am doing text extraction from resume(pdf,doc/Docx). I am getting text with space between each letter. E.g. WORK EXPERIENCE is coming as

W O R K
E X P E R I E N C E.

I want to get the *output as **WORK EXPERIENCE***. There might be any word like this, which I don't know in advance. How to handle this scenario? I would appreciate any direction/pointers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle this" exactly? What do you want to achieve, what did you try and what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following Python solution, I assume that W O R K E X P E R I E N C E and similar sequences are separately available and they are not all concatenated together. If they are concatenated the following code extracts a sequence of words.

I also assume that you can create your domain-specific lexicon (list of words) that you deal with. If such lexicon if not available, you can use nltk or enchanted English dictionaries.

```
# Create an English lexicon
vocabulary = set()

# Populate the vocabulary. You can also use an enchanted or nltk dictionary.
# I only add two words here but in practice you have to do this in a loop over your lexicon.
vocabulary.add('work')
vocabulary.add('experience')

# Put the letters (W O R K E X P E R I E N C E) here
yourData = 'W O R K E X P E R I E N C E'
yourData = yourData.lower().split(' ')

# Output goes here
output = ""

buffer = ""
# For adding a space before the captured words (starting from the second word)
startOfSeq = True
for letter in yourData:
    if letter != " ":
        buffer += letter
    # If the concatenated letters so far have a size greater than or equal to 2 and constitute a word
    if len(buffer) >= 2 and buffer in vocabulary:
        if startOfSeq:
            output += buffer
            startOfSeq = False
        else:
            output += " "
            output += buffer
        # Reset the buffer
        buffer = ""
print(output)
```

Comment: What if the word with spaced letter is not known in advance?

Comment: The words must be at least in the English vocabulary. Or in the vocabulary of your target language. You can import the English vocabulary using nltk or enchanted packages.

Comment: Won't your solution work for name of person with spaced letter?

Comment: No, not this solution. The thing with proper nouns (names) is that we either have to know them in advance or they must have characteristics such as having a capital first letter.